# cross-post question is deleted. why not to close instead?

Tags: support

please undelete my question https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/82604/genetical-distance-of-ones-parent-and-sibling-to-him-her-self and then close it, make it not possible to answer. why? because, this way, it will appear in search results, tag pages, it maybe linked with other related questions.

answer to chris:

then, could you please make it possible to answer to it only to users with some high reputation score and write a link to {this post in meta} in comments? i think that users would not answer to it.

2019-april-10:

i think, this is a math question in this stage, because some formulas can be developed on this stage, and only then it is possible to make questions, about, exactly what data from biology is required.

i asked this question in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3178144/genetical-distance-of-ones-parent-and-sibling-to-him-her-self and then asked in biology, following suggestions in comments.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94322/close-as-cross-post

Comment: Re: your edits, I don't think you are understanding why cross-posting is a problem. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu I think you are also not understanding the role of moderators vs. SE administrators, you are recommending solutions that are not available to moderators.

Answer (score 4):

This would leave an unanswered and closed question, which is not wanted on stackexchange. Additionally, this question would eventually be automatically deleted by the system as "closed abandoned". So even if we would undelete it right now, it would be removed again.

Comment: "This would leave an unanswered and closed question, which is not wanted on stackexchange" - i have seen many duplicate questions in these sites, they are not deleted. as i remember, some of them do not have any answers.

Comment: @qdinar Correct, for one thing it takes a while for this to happen, for the other this excludes questions which have gotten some attention. Still, I am against undeleting this question and creating another unanswered question, especially since cross-posting is also something not welcome here.

Comment: i do not understand "for one thing it takes a while for this to happen, for the other this excludes questions which have gotten some attention" . do you mean that deleting the duplicates is encouraged, wanted, but they are left undeleted just because it requires some work or it is not allowed by rules in case they have answers?

Comment: what do you thing about most voted opinions in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94322/close-as-cross-post and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16703/the-ability-to-link-cross-site-duplicates ?

Comment: @qdinar duplicate questions are different than other close reasons. Duplicate questions *can* be useful as a signpost to other questions. On the other hand, other closed questions (especially for unsalvagable & unanswerable) without answers are just not worth on SE.

Comment: @qdinar I have read this and I agree with Robert Harvey.